# are there any supervised learning methods that can only be applied to data with continuous features?

Tags: machine-learning, continuous-data

Are there any methods that exclusively work on continuous features? At first i imagined that linear models would demand this, but discrete values can be transformed and encoded such that they can be used (apparently).
[source - researchgate](https://www.researchgate.net/post/In_a_linear_regression_model_can_i_use_few_categorical_variables_as_independent_variables)

I suspect that there is some basic concept that i am totally oblivious to. Any pointers at all would be very helpful